# Bridge is not set. This is probably because you've explicitly synthesized the bridge in CodePush, even though it's inherited from RCTEventEmitter

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios, code-push

**The error I got is this:**

> ```
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error when sending event: CodePushDownloadProgress with body: {
>     receivedBytes = 1965637;
>     totalBytes = 1965637;
> }. Bridge is not set. This is probably because you've explicitly synthesized the bridge in CodePush, even though it's inherited from RCTEventEmitter.'
> ```

**This is how I wrap a React component:**

> ```
> export default CodePush(
>     {
>         updateDialog: false,
>         checkFrequency: CodePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME,
>         installMode: CodePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESTART
>     },
> )(App);
> ```

**Anyone know how to fix ?**

Comment: Did you find anything?>

Comment: Same issue. Any solution?